# Бинарное дерево - проблемы с insert и delete

Tags: c, binary

Необходимо построить бинарное дерево с методами inorder_tree_walk, tree_search, tree_minimum, tree_successor, tree_insert и tree_delete. Компилятор ругается на строки с tree->root. В коде не работают функции insert и delete, остальное, думаю, правильно. Код делался сугубо по Корману. На фото список ошибок. Подскажите, как исправить программу?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

struct tree {
    int key;
    struct tree *parent, *left, *right;
    struct tree *root;
};

void inorder_tree_walk(struct tree *x) {
    if (x != NULL)
    {
        inorder_tree_walk(x->left);
        printf("%d ", x->key);
        inorder_tree_walk(x->right);
    }
}

struct tree *tree_search(struct tree *x, int key) {
    if (x == NULL || key == x->key)
        return x;
    if (key < (x->key)) {
        return tree_search(x->left, key);
    }
    else{
        return tree_search(x->right, key);
    }
}

struct tree *tree_minimum(struct tree *x) {
    while (x->left != NULL)
        x = x->left;
        return x;
}

struct tree *tree_successor(struct tree *x) {
    struct tree *y;
    if (x->right != NULL) {
        return tree_minimum(x->right);
    }
    y = x->parent;

        while (y != NULL && x == y->right) {
            x = y;
            y = y->parent;
            return y;
        }
}

struct tree *tree_insert(struct tree *x, int key) 
{
    struct tree *z = NULL;
    struct tree *y = NULL;
    x = tree->root;
    while (x != NULL)
    {
        y = x;
        if (z->key < x->key)
            x = x->left;
        else
            x = x->right;
    }
    z->parent = y;

    if (y == NULL)
    {
        tree->root = z;
    }

    else if (z->key < y->key)
        y->left = z;

    else
        y->right = z;
}

struct tree *tree_delete(struct tree *tree, int key) {

    struct tree *z;
    struct tree *x;
    struct tree *y;

    if (z->left == NULL || z->right == NULL) {
        y = z;
    }

    else y = tree_successor(z);

    if (y->left != NULL)
        x = y->left;
    else x = y->right;

    if (x != NULL)
        x->parent = y->parent;

    if (y->parent = NULL)
        tree->root = x;

    else if (y = y->parent->left)
        y->parent->left = x;

    else y->parent->right = x;

    if (y != z)
    z->key = y->key;

    return y;
}

int main() {
    tree *root = NULL;
    root = tree_insert(root, 7);
    root = tree_insert(root, 13);
    root = tree_insert(root, 8);
    root = tree_insert(root, 23);
    root = tree_insert(root, -7);
    root = tree_insert(root, 13);
    root = tree_insert(root, 31);
    root = tree_insert(root, 5);
    inorder_tree_walk(root);
    printf("\n\n");

    tree *tmp;
    tmp = tree_minimum(root);
    printf("minimum = %d\n", tmp->key);

    root = tree_delete(root, 8);
    root = tree_delete(root, -7);
    root = tree_delete(root, 31);
    inorder_tree_walk(root);
    printf("\n\n");

    tmp = tree_search(root, 13);
    if (tmp == NULL) {
        printf("no element\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("found element\n");
    }
    getchar();
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `x = tree->root;` tree - это тип и его не можно использовать как переменную. А вот что там - это Вы должны знать как разработчик этого кода.

Comment: изменила tree на drzewo, выскакивает исключение "drzewo was nullptr" 

struct tree *tree_insert(struct tree *drzewo, int key) 
{
 struct tree *x = NULL;
 struct tree *z = NULL;
 struct tree *y = NULL;

 x = drzewo->root;
 while (x != NULL)
 {
  y = x;
  if (z->key < x->key)
   x = x->left;
  else
   x = x->right;
 }
 z->parent = y;

 if (y == NULL)
 {
  drzewo->root = z;
 }

 else if (z->key < y->key)
  y->left = z;

 else
  y->right = z;
 return 0;
}

Comment: @Yana Glance  Выберите конкретный язык, на котором должна быть написана программа. C и C++ - это два разных языка.

Answer (score 0):

tree - это имя тега структуры, а не имя объекта данного типа. Поэтому предложения подобное этому

```
x = tree->root;
```

некорректные.

Очевидно, что в связи с этим и другими ошибками функции `tree_insert` и `tree_delete` являются некорректными.

Для начала я бы удалил из определения структуры член данных `root`. Я не сомтрел все методы вашей реализации дерева, но на мой взгляд нет смысла в каждом узле дерева держать указатель на корневой узел.

```
struct tree {
    int key;
    struct tree *parent, *left, *right;
    struct tree *root;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
};
```

Структура может выглядеть следующим образом

```
struct tree {
    int key;
    struct tree *parent, *left, *right;
};
```

С учетом этого определения структуры функция `tree_insert`  может выглядеть одним из следующих образом, как будет показано ниже.

Обратите внимание, что, во-первых, функция должна возвращать указатель на корневой узел дерева, а у вас функция ничего не возвращает.

```
struct tree *tree_insert(struct tree *x, int key) 
{
    struct tree *z = NULL;
    struct tree *y = NULL;
    x = tree->root;
    while (x != NULL)
    {
        y = x;
        if (z->key < x->key)
            x = x->left;
        else
            x = x->right;
    }
    z->parent = y;

    if (y == NULL)
    {
        tree->root = z;
    }

    else if (z->key < y->key)
        y->left = z;

    else
        y->right = z;
}
```

К тому же переданный ей узел может быть равен `NULL`, однако в функции это обстоятельство полностью игнорируется.

Вот пара определений функции.

Либо функция может быть определена так.

```
struct tree * tree_insert(struct tree *root, int key)
{
    struct tree *parent = NULL;

    while (root != NULL)
    {
        parent = root;
        if (key < root->key)
        {
            root = root->left;
        }
        else
        {
            root = root->right;
        }
    }

    struct tree *node = (struct tree *)malloc(sizeof(struct tree));

    node->key = key;
    node->parent = parent;
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;

    if (parent != NULL)
    {
        if (key < parent->key)
        {
            parent->left = node;
        }
        else
        {
            parent->right = node;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        root = node;
    }

    return root;
}
```

Либо более компактно.

```
struct tree * tree_insert(struct tree *root, int key)
{
    struct tree *parent = NULL;
    struct tree **current = &root;

    while (*current  != NULL)
    {
        parent = *current;

        if (key < ( *current )->key)
        {
            current = &( *current )->left;
        }
        else
        {
            current = &(*current)->right;
        }
    }

    *current = (struct tree *)malloc(sizeof(struct tree));

    (*current)->key = key;
    (*current)->parent = parent;
    (*current)->left = NULL;
    (*current)->right = NULL;

    return root;
}
```

Я бы предпочел вторую реализацию.

Ниже представлена демонстрационная программа.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct tree * tree_insert(struct tree *root, int key)
{
    struct tree *parent = NULL;
    struct tree **current = &root;

    while (*current  != NULL)
    {
        parent = *current;

        if (key < ( *current )->key)
        {
            current = &( *current )->left;
        }
        else
        {
            current = &(*current)->right;
        }
    }

    *current = (struct tree *)malloc(sizeof(struct tree));

    (*current)->key = key;
    (*current)->parent = parent;
    (*current)->left = NULL;
    (*current)->right = NULL;

    return root;
}

void inorder_tree_walk( const struct tree *root ) 
{
    if (root != NULL)
    {
        inorder_tree_walk(root->left);
        printf("%d ", root->key);
        inorder_tree_walk(root->right);
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    tree *root = NULL;

    root = tree_insert(root, 7);
    root = tree_insert(root, 13);
    root = tree_insert(root, 8);
    root = tree_insert(root, 23);
    root = tree_insert(root, -7);
    root = tree_insert(root, 13);
    root = tree_insert(root, 31);
    root = tree_insert(root, 5);
    inorder_tree_walk(root);

    printf("\n\n");
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль будет следующим

```
-7 5 7 8 13 13 23 31
```

Этот вывод соответствует следующему дереву

```
     7
    /\
   /  \
  /    \
-7      13
 \     / \
  \   /   \
   6 8     23
          / \
         /   \
       13     31
```

С учетом сказанного вам также нужно будет исправить и другие функции, как, например, `tree_delete` и `tree_successor`. По крайней мере вам надо проверять переданные параметры на равенство `NULL`.